# Save email as .eml, with custom date

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, eml

I have emails in DB, and i want to save them as *.eml files.

```
SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
Client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
Client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"c:\aaa\import";
MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
...
Client.Send(Message);
```

This works, but it replace the Date header to the present date and time.
How can i define custom dates and times?

I found [this](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/csharp-create-eml.asp), but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there since you specify `PickupDirectory`.

Specify a different directory.

After saving, open up the file in your code and change the date and time.

Then move file to the `PickupDirectory` specified in your **IIS SMTP** settings.

Comment: Oh, this would be an ugly solution.

Comment: ugly and free, and not too difficult. The .eml is a text file. Date and time is probably the 2nd or 3rd line from the top.